# Get Amazon Connect Contact Lens Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am trying to retrieve programmatically Amazon Connect Contact Lens rules setup into S3 files for further movement into a Datawarehouse.

Using the link it seems rules can be listed and there content can be gathered via these API calls.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_ListRules.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeRule.html

Question- Do we know if this data is embedded within a database/table in AWS which can be queried and exported to S3 instead of making API call?